# Using itemprop="articleBody" on Multiple Elements (schema.org)

Tags: schema.org, microdata, structured-data

Is it bad practice to use `itemprop="articleBody"` on multiple elements. I ask because my page looks like this:

```
<main class="post content">
  <article itemscope itemType="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <header>
      <h1 itemprop="headline">My Blog Headline</h1>
      <p><time class="dt-published" itemprop="datePublished" pubdate datetime="2015-01-24 19:08:00">Jan 24, 2015</time></p>
      <p itemprop="author">Published by <a class="p-author h-card" itemprop="name" href="http://author.co.uk">Author Name</a></p>
    </header>

    <section itemprop="articleBody">
      <p>Article body</p>
      <p>Article body</p>
    </section>

    <section class="gallery">
      ...
    </section>

    <section itemprop="articleBody">
      <p>Article body</p>
      <p>Article body</p>
    </section>

  </article>
</main>
```

I've got a gallery that sits between my article body, is it ok to use `itemprop="articleBody"` on multiple `section`s like above?

P.S. Is it also bad practice to use `display: none` on my `itemprop="author"`? I don't want it to be part of the page design, is there another way around this?

Comment: Isn’t the gallery also part of the article (and therefore the body of the article)?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** As for your main question, I am in the same situation and I could not find evidence that this is a bad practice. **Multiple `articleBody`** tagging is not refused by the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool); this is not a proof of validity, but a clue.

---

**2)** As for your P.S. question about **hiding the author name**, you can replace this line:

```
<p itemprop="author">Published by <a class="p-author h-card" itemprop="name" href="http://author.co.uk">Author Name</a></p>
```

with these lines:

```
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Author Name" />
</div>
```

By the way, the above lines also state that `author` is a `Person` and not a `Thing`.